# pressing ENTER key do not work for JTextField in applet

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, japplet

I have a JTextField in a JApplet with a ActionListener. I compiled it using Eclipse and it works fine. But when I try to load it in a .html file using applet, the JTextField does not register/recognize the ENTER key when I press it. It seems like the ActionListener did not work. I used:

```
public void init() {
    textField = new JTextField(20);
    textField.setText("Enter your question here.");
    textField.selectAll();
    textField.addActionListener(this);

    textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    // Add Components to the Applet.
    GridBagLayout gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(gridBag);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gridBag.setConstraints(textField, c);
    contentPane.add(textField);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    gridBag.setConstraints(scrollPane, c);

    contentPane.add(scrollPane);

    newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String text = textField.getText();
    String question = "";
    String answer = "";

    question = textField.getText();
    question = ProcessString(question);
    answer = Answer(question);
    textArea.append(text + newline);
    textArea.append(answer + newline);
    textField.selectAll();
}

static String noAnswer;
static boolean knowAnswer = true;

// process the question string, take out non-ACSII characters, spaces, to
// lower space
public String ProcessString(String question) {
    question = question.toLowerCase();
    String[] words = question.split("\\s+");

    question = "";
    for (int wordCount = 0; wordCount < words.length; wordCount++) {
        words[wordCount] = words[wordCount].replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
        if (wordCount != words.length - 1)
            question = question + words[wordCount] + " ";
        else
            question = question + words[wordCount];
        // System.out.println(words[wordCount]);
    }
    return question;
}

public String Answer(String question) {

    String answer = "";

    /*
      if the database know the answer (did not not know), then return the
      answer. if the database does not know the answer, then recover the
      answer in database.
    */
    if (knowAnswer == true) {
        // open the database file and search if questions matches any one in
        // the
        // database
        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File("database.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int answerFrequency = 0;

        boolean matchFound = false;

        while (sc.hasNext()) {

            int questionCount = sc.nextInt();
            String line = sc.nextLine();

            String[] databaseLine = line.split("\\s+");
            String databaseQuestion = "";
            String databaseAnswer = "";

            // collect words for database questions
            for (int wordCount = 1; wordCount <= questionCount; wordCount++) {
                if (wordCount != questionCount)
                    databaseQuestion = databaseQuestion
                            + databaseLine[wordCount] + " ";
                else
                    databaseQuestion = databaseQuestion
                            + databaseLine[wordCount];
            }

            // collect words for database answer
            for (int wordCount = questionCount + 2; wordCount < databaseLine.length; wordCount++) {
                databaseAnswer = databaseAnswer + databaseLine[wordCount]
                        + " ";
            }

            // if the question is found in database, print answer
            if (question.equals(databaseQuestion)) {
                matchFound = true;

                // the current answer is more frequency than the previous
                // found
                // answer, reassign the current answer the find answer
                if (answerFrequency < Integer
                        .parseInt(databaseLine[questionCount + 1])) {
                    answerFrequency = Integer
                            .parseInt(databaseLine[questionCount + 1]);
                    answer = databaseAnswer;
                }
            }
        }

        if (matchFound == true) {
            // System.out.println(answer);
            knowAnswer = true;
        } else {
            // System.out.println("I don't know what you mean. How should I answer your question?");
            knowAnswer = false;
            noAnswer = question;
            answer = "I don't know how to respond. How should I answer that?";
        }

        sc.close();
    } else if (knowAnswer == false) {
        String[] word = noAnswer.split(" ");

        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        answer = question;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("database.txt", true));
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write(word.length + " " + noAnswer + " 1 " + answer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Cannot write to file");
            }
        }
        answer = "I got that.";
        knowAnswer = true;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Works fine for me, got any more source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me....

```
public class TestApplet04 extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private String newline;

    public void init() {
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.setText("Enter your question here.");
        textField.selectAll();
        textField.addActionListener(this);

        textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        // Add Components to the Applet.
        GridBagLayout gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(gridBag);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBag.setConstraints(textField, c);
        contentPane.add(textField);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        gridBag.setConstraints(scrollPane, c);

        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String text = textField.getText();
        String question = "";
        String answer = "";

        question = textField.getText();
//        question = ProcessString(question);
//        answer = Answer(question);
        textArea.append(text + newline);
        textArea.append(answer + newline);
        textField.selectAll();
    }
}
```

**Updated after feedback**

Here's you major problem...

```
sc = new Scanner(new File("database.txt"));
```

This is going to cause you a number of problems.  First of all, the applet isn't likely to have access rights to read from the client machine, so you're likely to run into a security exception.  Secondly, as the previous statement may have suggested, the file ins't likely to exist on the client machine.

You need to embed this resource within the Jar of your application and use `getClass().getResource("...")` to gain access to it.  This will return a `URL`, from which you can use `URL#openConnection` to gain access to a `InputStream`, which can use in your scanner.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. If I take out the ProcessString(); and Answer(); functions, then the code work. But if I have them in the same JApplet class then it does not work. Even if I take out the functions and put them in a separate class (and call the class functions), it still does not work. So basically, calling those functions some how made it not working in .html applet.

Comment: S, we would need to see the ProcessString & Answer methods to know more

Comment: It's kinda messy, but here it is. I was trying to read a text file and/or write to a text file in those functions. I pasted at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have the file in the same directory. But it looks like I need to go back to the drawing board and learn some basics. I migrated this from a local application, so I need to learn about web applications.

Comment: You can take a look at http://littletutorials.com/2008/03/26/locating-resources-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an Action to the ActionMap and setting the InputMap up for ENTER key.

```
textField.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "enter" );
textField.getActionMap().put("enter", new AbstractAction() {...} );
```

The field will have to have focus.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but should I put the code in public void init()? And it "cannot resolve KeyStroke".

Comment: @user1793092 `import javax.swing.KeyStroke;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a newbie to Java, but found out that `JTextfield` is only a single line entry.
If you want a multiline entry, you would need to use a `JTextArea` instead.

Hope this helps :)